# Python Dictionary Key trouble in a loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I am to  write a function `buildtour(start, locations)` where start is a string corresponding to the name of a location in locations. The tour should consist of the closest consecutive location from the 'start'. As an example:

```
print(buildtour("myhotel", [("ngv", 4, 0), ("town hall", 4, 4),("myhotel",  2, 2), ("fed square",  4, 2)]))
```

should return

```
["myhotel", "fed square", "ngv", "town hall"]
```

The input is done automatically through a submission so locations is always changing and therefore cannot be manually defined into a dictionary. I can see that in the loop that I've defined start as the closest place (which should be the next starting point of the tour) but it returns a key error.
My current code is:

```
import math

def distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):                                                    
    return math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)


def buildtour(start, locations):
    tour_list = [start]
    places = [u[0] for u in locations]
    coordinates = {}
    for item in locations:
      coordinates[item[0]] = item[1:]
    i = 0
    while i <= len(coordinates):
        p = 0
        distances = []
        x2y2 = coordinates.pop(start)
        x2 = x2y2[0]
        y2 = x2y2[1]
        x1 = [j[0] for i, j in coordinates.items()]
        y1 = [j[1] for i, j in coordinates.items()]
        while p <= (len(coordinates)-1):
            avg_distance = distance(x1[p], y1[p], x2, y2)
            distances.append(avg_distance)
            p += 1
            closest_place = sorted(zip(distances, places), key=lambda distances: distances[0])
            closest_place = [u[1] for u in closest_place][0]
            tour_list.append(closest_place)
        start = closest_place
    return tour_list
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Where* is the KeyError? Please provide  the full traceback together with an idea of what `locations` looks like. I'd suggest reading how to provide a [mcve] as well.

Comment: Testing the first example from the question. Your submission raised an exception of type KeyError. This occurred on line 17 of program.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `x2y2 = coordinates.pop(0)`.

The problem is that `pop` is a method that accepts the **index** of the list that is to be removed, not a string (e.g. the value of `start` in your code).

Answer (score 0):

Your code becomes much shorter if you use a dict. You can create it dynamically, with names as keys and coordinates as values.

If you only use distances to sort places, you don't even need to use `math.sqrt`.

```
start = "myhotel"

locations = [("ngv", 4, 0), ("town hall", 4, 4),
             ("myhotel",  2, 2), ("fed square",  4, 2)]
locations_dict = {n: (x, y) for n, x, y in locations}
# => {'ngv': (4, 0), 'town hall': (4, 4), 'myhotel': (2, 2), 'fed square': (4, 2)}

def distance2(name1, name2, locations_dict):
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = *locations_dict[name1], *locations_dict[name2]
    return (x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2

print(sorted(locations_dict.keys(),
             key=lambda name: distance2(start, name, locations_dict)))
# => ['myhotel', 'fed square', 'ngv', 'town hall']
```

Note that in Python, you almost never have to define arrays and dicts the old way, by  initializing them first and adding elements one by one. There's probably a shorter, more Pythonic way to do it.